# Why is there a line around my three.js canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm using a version of [this](https://codepen.io/matheus-peres/pen/YmKNvd) code on my website and I've made the background transparent so there's just particles showing over my webpage. I've noticed that there's a small border around my canvas that harbors these particles. It appears to be around 1 pixel wide (I can't post images yet but [here's](https://i.ibb.co/S5b7m8K/Screen-Shot-2019-07-18-at-1-41-54-PM.png) a link to it. **Edit:** fixed link)

I've tried setting outlines and borders to none in my CSS file but it doesn't appear to be a CSS problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is how I'm making the canvas transparent if that helps at all

**Javascript**

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: document.getElementById("map"),
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true,
});
renderer.setSize(ww, wh);
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000,0);
```

I'd like for the full background to be transparent and for there to be no border. It's especially obvious on mobile devices.

Comment: Does it work if you set `premultipliedAlpha` to `true` for the particles material? Maybe related https://discourse.threejs.org/t/canvastexture-strange-shadow/5712

Comment: I have tried this and the other suggestions from that thread and they don't appear to work. The issue isn't that pressing but it is a bit baffling since it doesn't seem to appear on Firefox  but does in Chrome? Thanks for the suggestion though : )

Answer (score 1):

This could be help someone:

considering you have canvas element on your html view then code should be,

```
canvas { outline: none; border: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found the answer to this question yet, the answer is adding `overflow: hidden;`to your div/canvas containing three.js scene.